# ' t ' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

Hi guys bear with my as I've started learning c++ yesterday.

I want to create objects dependent upon the values I am reading in from a file. However it is saying that the value t is not declared within the scope:

Also I understand if the way I'm doing my code isn't necessarily the best practice. As a general coding concept I was wondering how would I initialise t beforehand as the objects that I'm creating are dependent upon the value given

Here is the code:

```
 while(getline(linestream,value,',')){
            if(i==0){
                cout<< "Type " << value << endl;
                type = value;
            }
            else if(i==1){
                cout<< "Code " << value << endl;
                code = value;
            }
            else if (i==2){
                cout << "Count " << value << endl;
                count = atoi(value.c_str());
            }
            else if (i ==3){
                cout << "Price " << value << endl;
                price = atoi(value.c_str());
            }
            else if(i ==4){
                cout << "Other " << value << endl;
                other = value;
            }
            i++;
            if(i ==5){
                if(type == "transistor"){
                    Transistor *t = new Transistor(code,count,price,other);
                }else if (type == "IC"){
                    IC *t = new IC(code,count,price,other);
                }else if (type == "resistor"){
                    Resistor *t = new Resistor(code,count,price,other);
                }else if (type == "capacitor"){
                    Capacitor *t = new Capacitor(code,count,price,other);
                }else{
                    Diode *t = new Diode(code,count,price,other);
                }

                if(counter ==0){
                    LinkedList list(t);
                }else{
                    list.tailAppend(t);
                }
            }
        }
```

Also all the classes that I'm creating potential objects for are all derived from the base class StockItem

Comment: Are `Transistor`, `Resistor` etc. all sub-classes of some class (e.g. `Component`)? If so, then you could declare a `Component* t` before the `if` checks and then use polymorphism to initialise this depending upon the `if`-statement executed.

Comment: Yes @ArchbishopOfBanterbury (love the name btw) they are all derived from a base class, but its an abstract base class

Comment: @Blarsssss That's fine, you can still create a pointer to this base class and then assign it an instance of a derived class as you've done in the `if` checks - e.g: declare `Base * t` initially then do `t = new Transistor(...)` and so on for each if-statement.

Comment: @Blarsssss And BlackAdder says: Provide a [MCVE] please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t` is not in the right scope for you to use. You declared it in the block after the `if` statement(s). Instead, you should declare it as a base class before the code blocks, and initialize it to child classes after each if statement (which you should really use `switch` instead, but this isn't codereview)

Comment: There is also the same problem with `list`.

Comment: getting invalid new-expression of abstract class type

Comment: @Blarsssss, doing what?

Comment: You are right @SergeyA, Just got myself stuck at that barrier too haha!

Answer (score 1):

In C++ all the loops and `if` clauses have their own scope. So you should declare `t` outside of the `if` clauses, and you should declare `list` outside of the loop. Also C++ is the language with strict variable types, so you can't change the type of `t`, neither you can push values of different types to a list. To do so you should either use pointers `void*` with no type or create a parent class and derive all the different types you use for `t` from that class (then you cold use a pointer to a base class for `t` in that case). If you don't know how to do this, you would better read some books on object oriented programming in C++, it's too vast topic to explain in this answer.

The good book on this topic might be one of the books of Bjarne Stroustrup found, for example, [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/).